# Finding exceptions and optimisations in weather forecast service

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

When creating a new Blazor project, there is a page called `FetchData` which gives an example of a razor page using a service to pull data to a page.

I set myself a challenge to improve on the service, so that instead of a random label being assigned to a temperature for a forecast, it separates the label categories evenly across the range of temperatures.

Here is the original code for the service:

> ```
> namespace MyBlazorApp.Data
> {
>     public class WeatherForecastService
>     {
>         private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
>         {
>             "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
>         };
>
>         public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync(DateTime startDate)
>         {
>             return Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
>             {
>                 Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
>                 TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
>                 Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
>             }).ToArray());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

And here is my new code:

```
namespace MyBlazorApp.Data
{
    public class WeatherForecastService
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync(DateTime startDate)
        {
            var minTemp = -10;
            var maxTemp = 40;

            return Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Range(0, 14).Select(index => getWeatherForecast(startDate, minTemp, maxTemp, index)).ToArray());
        }

        public WeatherForecast getWeatherForecast(DateTime startDate, int minTemp, int maxTemp, int index)
        {
            maxTemp += (maxTemp - minTemp) % Summaries.Length;

            var rng = Random.Shared.Next(minTemp, maxTemp);
            var categorySize = (maxTemp - minTemp) / (Summaries.Length);
            var pointer = (rng + (0 - minTemp)) / categorySize;

            if (pointer >= Summaries.Length)
            {
                pointer = Summaries.Length - 1;
            }


            return new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng,
                Summary = Summaries[pointer]
            };

        }
    }
}
```

The code seems to work fine, but I feel that the error handling as well as the code optimization, readability and simplicity can be improved. Any tips on how I can look to find these improvements myself would also be extremely helpful. I changed some of the numbers to feel more appropriate to the context, but ideally the solution should work no matter what variables are set.

In summary, I am trying to find a solution to the problem in the absolute best way possible, as a way of giving an example of what *perfect* code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The `GetForecastAsync` method

- Since you always call it with `DateTime.Now` from `FetchData.razor` you should consider to remove `startDate` as a parameter
- Nothing indicates that this method should be async, so you could convert it to back to sync

You could replace the `OnInitializedAsync` override with the following code:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
  => forecasts = ForecastService.GetForecastForTwoWeeks();
```

The `GetForecastAsync` could be replaced with this:

```
public WeatherForecast[] GetForecastForTwoWeeks()
    => Enumerable.Range(0, 14)
        .Select(daysSinceStart => GetWeatherForecast(DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysSinceStart)))
        .ToArray();
```

- Since `14` is hard-coded inside the method I would suggest to add this constraint/restriction to the method name (`GetForecastForTwoWeeks`)
- Since `minTemp` and `maxTemp` are **constants** and used only inside the `GetWeatherForecast` I've moved them from here
- The `startDate` and `index` are always used together inside the `GetWeatherForecast` to calculate the new Date

  - So, rather than passing them separately you could pass the calculated date

#### The `getWeatherForecast` method

- I would suggest to use C# standard naming guideline and name it with Pascal Case (`GetWeatherForecast`)
- I would also suggest to make it `private` if it is used only by the `GetForecastForTwoWeeks` method

You could rewrite the `getWeatherForecast` like this

```
const int MinTemperature = -10, MaxTemperature = 40;
static readonly int AdjustedMaxTemperature = MaxTemperature + (MaxTemperature - MinTemperature) % Summaries.Length;
static readonly int CategorySize = (AdjustedMaxTemperature - MinTemperature) / Summaries.Length;
private static WeatherForecast GetWeatherForecast(DateTime date)
{
    var temperature = Random.Shared.Next(MinTemperature, AdjustedMaxTemperature);
    var summaryIndex = (temperature - MinTemperature) / CategorySize;

    return new ()
    {
        Date = date,
        TemperatureC = temperature,
        Summary = Summaries[summaryIndex]
    };
}
```

- `Temp` can abbreviate multiple terms (like *temporarily*, *temperature*, etc.) so, it might make sense to avoid abbreviating here
- I would advise you to avoid overwriting method's parameter value (`maxTemp += ...`)
- The adjusted maximum temperature and the category size are always the same

  - So, they could be calculated only once
- BTW the `AdjustedMaxTemperature` is the same as the `MaxTemperature` since `(MaxTemperature - MinTemperature) % Summaries.Length` is 0
- `+ (0 - minTemp)` can be simplified to `-minTemp`
- This `pointer >= Summaries.Length` condition check is not needed, it will never be `true`
- `rng` does not mean anything, whereas `temperature` is more meaningful/expressive IMHO

---

The most concise version I can think of now (*which is still readable*):

```
private const int MinTemperature = -10, MaxTemperature = 40;
private static readonly int AdjustedMaxTemperature = MaxTemperature + (MaxTemperature - MinTemperature) % Summaries.Length;
private static readonly int CategorySize = (AdjustedMaxTemperature - MinTemperature) / Summaries.Length;

public WeatherForecast[] GetForecastForTwoWeeks()
    => (from daysSinceStart in Enumerable.Range(0, 14)
        let temperature = Random.Shared.Next(MinTemperature, AdjustedMaxTemperature)
        let summaryIndex = (temperature - MinTemperature) / CategorySize
        select new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysSinceStart),
            TemperatureC = temperature,
            Summary = Summaries[summaryIndex]
        })
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the detailed answer. I will try to apply this knowledge in my future work!

Comment: For the removal of `pointer >= Summaries.Length` - If the temperature values were adjusted so that they weren't fully divisible by the `Summaries` list length, a remainder would be created from the calculations which would create an index out of range exception without the code above. But for the initial values it would be fine. I should have specified this in the original question.

Comment: @AT123 I've provided suggestions based on your provided code. Any requirement can invalidate my suggest so you should evaluate them whenever you receive a new.